# How I can explode all string fields in Collection using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array with fields

```
[
  "house" => "30|30|30",
  "street" => "first|second|third",
  ...
]
```

I want to get array

```
[
  [
     "house" => "30",
     "street" => "first",
     ...
  ],
  [
     "house" => "30",
     "street" => "second",
     ...
  ],
  [
     "house" => "30",
     "street" => "third",
     ...
  ]
]
```

I know how I can solve this using PHP and loop, but maybe this problem has more beautiful solution

Comment: Is `30|30|30` in a database? Can you add more details about where data is coming from, likely fixing it at that point is best.

Comment: What have you tried? You've got multiple "pipe-separated" strings, which you can convert to arrays via `explode('|', ...)` and map them to a new array. Please remember that Stackoverflow is not a free coding service; you're expected to make an effort to solve your own issue before asking for assistance.

Comment: Of course I solved this problem, and I didn't ask about simple solution via explode
I noticed that data is similar to each other and maybe Laravel has method in one of the classes (for example Collection), which solve this problem in one-two lines

Answer (score 2):

use zip

```
$data = [
  "house" => "30|30|30",
  "street" => "first|second|third",
];

$house = collect(explode('|',$data['house']));
$street = collect(explode('|',$data['street']));

$out = $house->zip($street);

$out->toarray();
```

Comment: Thanks, it’s a good solution, but I mean that in each array may be more than two fields

Comment: If this is data coming from a form, a simple renaming of the form fields will produce better data

Comment: I received this data from the third party service

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I managed to do with tinker.

```php
$original = [
    "house" => "30|30|30",
    "street" => "first|second|third",
];

$new = []; // technically not needed. data_set will instantiate the variable if it doesn't exist.
foreach ($original as $field => $values) {
    foreach (explode('|', $values) as $index => $value) {
        data_set($new, "$index.$field", $value);
    }
}

/* dump($new)
[
    [
        "house" => "30",
        "street" => "first",
    ],
    [
        "house" => "30",
        "street" => "second",
    ],
    [
        "house" => "30",
        "street" => "third",
    ],
]
*/
```

I tried using collections, but the main problem is the original array's length is not equal to the resulting array's length, so map operations don't really work. I suppose you can still use `each` though.

```php
$new = []; // Since $new is used inside a Closure, it must be declared.
collect([
        "house" => "30|30|30",
        "street" => "first|second|third",
        ...
    ])
    ->map(fn($i) => collect(explode('|', $i))
    ->each(function ($values, $field) use (&$new) {
        $values->each(function ($value, $index) use ($field, &$new) {
            data_set($new, "$index.$field", $value);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $array = ["house" => "30|30|30","street" => "first |second| third"];
            foreach($array as $key=> $values){
                $explodeval = explode('|',$values);
                for($i=0; $i<count($explodeval); $i++){
                    $newarray[$i][$key]= $explodeval[$i];
                }
                
            }
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [house] => 30
            [street] => first
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [house] => 30
            [street] => second
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [house] => 30
            [street] => third
        )

)
```